# Formatting a DSP param value

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm trying to format a DSP param string value to be a specific length (padded with zeros). I believe this can be done using jstl format number function, but not sure how to tie the 2 together.

I have:

```
<dsp:droplet name="IsEmpty">
<dsp:param name="value" param="ean"/>
<dsp:oparam name="false">
```

At which point I need to format the "ean" string to be "x" number of characters before passing it to a droplet.

I've looked at using:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${ean}" maxIntegerDigits="13"/>
```

But not sure if this overwrites the existing param value or not...

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatNumber to format a number to a specific length using a pattern.  A 0 in a pattern means to show the number if present, else a zero.

Here's how you can format the ${ean} value to 13 digits with zero-padding; the result will be put into ${eanFormatted}.  If you don't specify a var parameter, it will print the output.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${ean}" type="number" 
                  pattern="0000000000000" var="eanFormatted" />
```

For example:

```
ean=${ean} formatted=${eanFormatted}
```

will output:

```
ean=1234 formatted=000000001234
```